# Assign 25 identical items to 8 different people

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

In how many different ways $24$ identical gifts can be shared between $8$ different people such that

1. One of them doesn't accept more than $2$ gifts , and
2. The other people accept maximum of $5$ gifts.

(Similar problems are in Combinatorics a guided tour pdf book in the chapter of Algebraic, generating functions).

Comment: Tried to clean up the question as best as I could. What have you tried? please show some work or any idea on what you tried or failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $N\in\{24,25\}$. The generating function is
$$g(x):=(1+x+x^2)(1+x+\ldots+x^5)^7={(1-x^3)(1-x^6)^7\over(1-x)^8}\ .$$
Now collect all terms of degree $\leq N$ of the polynomial $g_1(x):=(1-x^3)(1-x^6)^7$, and note that
$$g_2(x):={1\over(1-x)^8}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{7+k\choose k}x^k\ .$$
Now find the coefficient of $x^N$ in the product $g_1(x)g_2(x)$.

Comment: why N e (24,25)? thanks for your help...

Comment: Because in the title of your question you talk about $25$, and in the text about $24$.